# Move the object back to its original postion in ActionScript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

Here is a script for a Drag n Drop game which I am working on. I've made each object draggable, and now I want the objects to return to its original positions once they're not dropped in its current location.

ie;I want to drag an object to a particular place.In case I release that dragged object before I reach that particular area ,the object should come to its initial place where I object was dragged from

```
public function mouseDownEvent(mouseEvent:MouseEvent):void 
{
    draging = true;
}

public function mouseUpEvent(mouseEvent:MouseEvent):void 
{
    draging = false;
    selectedObject.stopDrag();
}

public function mouseMoveEvent(mouseEvent:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(draging==true)
    {
        selectedObject.startDrag(true);
    } 
    else 
    {
        selectedObject.stopDrag();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

selectedObject.setPosition(info.point.x,info.point.y,info.point.z);